# translate sql query to activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a line of code looking like this

```
    @words =  Word.connection.select_all("select text, count(*) as occurs from words join works on words.work_id = works.id where works.grouping == 'group1' group by text order by occurs desc limit 10")
```

I would like to write it in a more rails/active record way but the syntax is still quite new to me.

each work has many words, each word belongs to one work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code works for you:

```
Word.includes(:works).where("works.grouping == 'group1'").limit(10).count(:group => :text)
```

The `includes` method create a join with your works table. The `where` method is for conditions, the `limit` is self explanatory and the `count` with `group` by a column too.